# Rigidbody keeps moving in Unity (AddForce)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make my rigidbody sphere move with the "WASD" keys, and so far it works except for a little problem. When I move the rigidbody, it keeps moving infinitely.

This is my code:

```
rig.AddForce(cam.transform.forward * movementForce * Time.deltaTime, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
```

Full code: https://pastebin.com/ntjAfDVv

Answer (score 1):

Well if you don't press any key then you don't stop ... You keep moving with whatever the current velocity is.

Also note that for the `s` key you multiply by `movementForce * Time.deltaTime * tempAirMultiplier` **twice** which will most probably result in a significantly lower force then expected!

I would probably do something like e.g.

```
    // Tracks if any of the WASD keys is pressed
    var gotInput = false;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rig.AddForce(cam.transform.forward * movementForce * Time.deltaTime * tempAirMultiplier, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        gotInput = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        rig.AddForce(cam.transform.right * -movementForce * Time.deltaTime * tempAirMultiplier, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        gotInput = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
    {
        var force = cam.transform.forward * -movementForce * Time.deltaTime * tempAirMultiplier; // Get relative movement
        // you can simply erase one component like this, no need to create a new Vector3 instance
        force.y = 0; 
        // Note that force already contains your multipliers "Time.deltaTime * movementForce * tempAirMultiplier"
        rig.AddForce(force, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        gotInput = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
    {
        rig.AddForce(cam.transform.right * tempAirMultiplier, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        gotInput = true;
    }

    // If none of the keys is pressed stop the rigidbody
    if(!gotInput)
    {
        rig.veolcity = Vector3.zero;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetKey` returns true **while** the user holds down the key identified by the key KeyCode enum parameter. Check [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html). So you might be adding lots of forces.

Maybe you need to try [Input.GetKeyDown](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKeyDown.html) that returns true **during the frame** the user starts pressing down the key identified by name.

Answer (score 0):

I actually could solve the problem by doing this.
My answer:

```
rigid.drag = 1;
```

Inisde the FixedUpdate() function

Comment: Why would you do this in `FixedUpdate` .. it would be enough to do this **once** or even already via the Inspector..